# Loops and Character methods

Tags: java, validation, user-input

I am a little stuck on part 3 of this program that I am working on. Here are the requirements:

1. The program will prompt the user for a valid last name, reprompting until a valid last name is entered. A last name is valid if it contains only letters and spaces, it begins and ends with a letter, and it does not contain 2 consecutive spaces.
2. The program then prompts for a year of birth. Valid birth years are integers between 1900 and 1999, inclusive, but your program must reprompt on non-numeric input. Implicitly, this means you must read the data as a string.
3. Finally, the program prompts for a valid Wisconsin driver's license number. It will have the format LDDD-DDDD-DDDD-DD, where L is a capital letter and each D is a digit. For example, 
   A123-4567-8901-23. The program reprompts until a valid number, including dashes, is entered.
4. For these inputs to be consistent, the first letter of the last name must match the first letter of the driver's license number. Case is ignored, so a last name of “el Guapo” would match a driver's license number beginning with “E”. Also, the last 2 digits of the year of birth are encoded in the driver's license number (denoted by Y): LDDD-DDDY-YDDD-DD. So A123-4567-8901-23 would belong to a person born in 1978. If the last name, year of birth, and driver's license number are consistent the program prints consistent; otherwise, it prints fraudulent.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program06
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);

        boolean legal = false;
        boolean space = false;

        String name;
        String yearStr = null;
        String licenseNumber;
        int yearInt;

        // while legal is false, loop
        while (!legal)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter a last name: ");
            name = stdIn.nextLine();

            legal = true; // legal will be true, until illegal input found

            if (Character.isLetter(name.charAt(0)) 
                && Character.isLetter(name.charAt(name.length() - 1)))
            {

                // if first and last characters are letters, check rest, else is
                // illegal

                for (int i = 0; i < name.length() && legal; i++)
                {
                    // walking through name, checking each letter.
                    // if legal = false, will break loop

                    if (Character.isLetter(name.charAt(i)))
                    {
                        space = false; // resetting space
                    }
                    else if (name.charAt(i) == ' ')
                    {
                        // making sure not 2 spaces in a row
                        if (!space)
                        {
                            space = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            legal = false;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        legal = false;
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    legal = false;
                }
            }

            legal = false;

            while (!legal)
            {
                System.out.println("Enter year of birth: ");
                yearStr = stdIn.nextLine();  

                if (yearStr.matches("19[\\d][\\d]"))
                {
                    legal = true;
                }
            }

            legal = false;

            while (!legal)
            {
                System.out.println("Enter driver's license number: ");
                 licenseNumber = stdIn.nextLine();  

                // Here
                if (licenseNumber.matches("\\p{Lu}"))
                {
                    legal = true; 
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

At that third while loop at the bottom (marked as `// Here`) you can see that I used `\\p{Lu}` inside the 
`if (licenseNumber.matches("\\p{Lu}")){` statement. This obviously only tests for the capital letter, not for the validity of the rest of the 'driver's license number'. What condition would work?

Answer (score 0):

Practically all validation can be done using `String.matches()`, which uses regex to assert the input has a certain format.

To validate the last name:

```
input.matches("^(?!.*  )(?i)[a-z]([a-z ]*[a-z])?")
```

This allows for the edge case of a single letter being the last name, which technically satisfies the requirements. A negative look-ahead is used to check there aren't two adjacent spaces. `(?i`) makes the regex case insensitive, taking case of case.

---

To validate year of birth:

```
input.matches("19\\d\\d")
```

Fairly straightforward.

---

To validate drivers license *format*:

```
input.matches("[A-Z]\\d(\\d\\d-\\d\\d){3}")
```

I noticed that the pattern is "letter", "digit" then 3 groups of "digit digit dash digit digit", so I coded it like that.

---

To validate drivers license *content*:

```
license.charAt(0) == lastName.toUpperCase().charAt(0) &&
  license.charAt(8) == yearOfBirth.charAt(2) &&
  license.charAt(10) == yearOfBirth.charAt(3);
```

Comment: Ahhh still getting used to '.matches' .  So in parameter 4 of the directions, I would use char() method to check if the last name, year of birth, and driver's license number are "consistent" or "fraudulent"?

Comment: All validation in the program can be done using `matches()`, with just a little extra checking *between* the fields.

Comment: I've added all the code you should need for validation. No need for loops or lots of code - the whole test can be done as the loop condition, probably a `do while` is what you want.

Comment: Everything is working fine, I just keep on getting "Fraudulent" even if the name, d.o.b., and drivers license number are consistent. What I have :  https://gist.github.com/anonymous/064204b8c728464d4b1b

Comment: That linked code isn't using the code from my answer, so you're on your own.

Comment: Nevermind! The code you had that validates drivers license content was off by two digits. It should be license.charAt(8) and license.charAt(10). Thanks Bohemian! Much appreciated!

Comment: Ahhh! I made a noob error of using one-based indexing :/ Cheers.